# Regex to match multiple different words

Tags: java, regex

I have following type of words to match:

> anyword_ratings_.anyword_anyword.txt.20221110 movie.txt.20221110
>
> anyword_ratings_.anyword_anyword.doc.20221111 movie.txt.20221111

I want to match all words before and after rating but also one movie file with variable date

I did try the below but doesn't work.

```
.*(ratings|movie)*.(txt|doc){d{4}\d{2}\d{2}}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, I don't understand well what you want to match, maybe an output of your inputs can help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you post correctly, to parse the string the way you want I think would be rather difficult with RegEx however you could parse it this way:

```
String str = "anyword_ratings_.anyword_anyword.doc.20221111 movie.txt.20221111";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
str = str.trim();
String[] parts = str.split("\\s+");
String firstPart = parts[0];
String secondPart = parts[1];
   
String beforeRatings = firstPart.substring(0, firstPart.indexOf("ratings")).replace("_", " ").trim();
   
String afterRatings = firstPart.substring(firstPart.indexOf("ratings") + 7, firstPart.lastIndexOf(".")).trim();
while (afterRatings.startsWith("_") || afterRatings.startsWith(".")) {
    afterRatings = afterRatings.substring(1);
}
   
String ratingDateString = firstPart.substring(firstPart.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
LocalDate ratingDate = LocalDate.parse(ratingDateString, dtf);
   
String movieFile = secondPart.substring(0, secondPart.lastIndexOf("."));
String movieDateString = secondPart.substring(secondPart.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
   
LocalDate movieDate = LocalDate.parse(movieDateString, dtf);
   
// Display variables in Console Window:
System.out.println("Before Ratings: " + beforeRatings);
System.out.println("After Ratings:  " + afterRatings);
System.out.println("Ratings Date:   " + ratingDate + " (LocalDate Type \"yyyy-MM-dd\")");
System.out.println("Movie File:     " + movieFile);
System.out.println("Movie Date:     " + movieDate + " (LocalDate Type \"yyyy-MM-dd\")");
```

The Console Window would display:

```
Before Ratings: anyword
After Ratings:  anyword_anyword.doc
Ratings Date:   2022-11-11 (LocalDate Type "yyyy-MM-dd")
Movie File:     movie.txt
Movie Date:     2022-11-11 (LocalDate Type "yyyy-MM-dd")
```